# Postgresql vertical to horizontal, one table

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a small glossary in postgresql.
Until now, I have a table with some "vertical values"

```
General_id  Sing_id     Synonim     Language
1           1               yes             en-GB
2           1               ja              de-DE
3           1               oui             fr-FR
4           2               no              en-GB
5           2               nein            de-DE
6           2               niet            ru-RU


SELECT 
    General_id,
    Sing_id,
    Synonim,
    Language
FROM table1.base
```

but I would like to have it like this:

```
Sing_id   en_GB   de_DE   fr_FR   ru_RU    ...

  1         yes      ja      oui
  2         no       nein           niet    ...
```

Would you like to give me a hint on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about 'pivoting'.

See this post: [Pivoting in Postgres](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/06/27/Pivoting-in-Postgres/)

Example from post:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT
    a date,
    b.desc AS os,
    (random() * 10000 + 1)::int AS value
     FROM generate_series((now() - ''100 days''::interval)::date, now()::date, ''1 DAY''::interval) a,
          (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[''OSX'', ''Windows'', ''Linux'']) AS DESC) b ORDER BY 1,2
  ','SELECT unnest(ARRAY[''OSX'', ''Windows'', ''Linux''])'
) 
AS ct(date date, OSX int, Windows int, Linux int);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try the crosstab function. I also found this one: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html